# GSAP - Prevent cropping from easing

Tags: animation, svg, gsap

We're using the MorphSVG plugin from GSAP and the "Back" easing which creates an elastic effect.

You can see it in action here

```
tl.to('#close', 1, {
    morphSVG: {
      shape: '#open',
    },
    fill: '#00ADEF',
    ease: Back.easeInOut
});
```

https://codepen.io/owenmelbz/pen/RLVMvo?editors=1111

However the easing takes the item out of the viewport and crops it.

How could we avoid this cropping?

Thanks

Comment: set `overflow:visible` style on the svg element.

Comment: Seems to work on my phone! Will try out tomoz to confirm it’s all good 